# Display.findDisplay(t) returns null on all my Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, swt

I'm currently working on an Mehtod that searches all SWT Displays with Shells:

```
 /**
 * retrieves all display objects of all threads  which have shells
 * 
 * @return list of displays
 */
public static ArrayList getAllDisplays(){
    Display display = null;
    ArrayList<Display> retVal = new ArrayList<Display> ();

    for(Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()){
        logger.info ("currentThread set to: " + t);
        if (t != null) {
            logger.info ("currentThread is not null");
            display = Display.findDisplay(t);
            logger.debug ("display: " + display);
            if(display!=null) {
                boolean b = hasShells(display) ;
                logger.debug("b: " + b);
                if( b ){
                    logger.debug("found a display with shells ! ");
                    retVal.add(display);
                }
            }
        }
        logger.info ("Next Thread");
    }
    return retVal;

}
```

Now im trying to process an SWT Application with this, but `Display.findDisplay(t);` returns null all the time.

How is it possible that none of the Threads are UI-Threads? Do i miss some Threads with `Display.findDisplay(t);`?

Thanks!

Comment: Works on my Mac. When are you calling this? Has the `Display` actually been created yet?

Comment: It works for me too with most SWT Applications but, i have here one special Application that causes the `Display.findDisplay(t);` to return always `null`. So the question is "What could the developer of this special application have done to his Threads that none of them are UI-Threads?".

Comment: Are you sure it is an SWT app and not Swing or JavaFX or no GUI at all?

Comment: I see with the the spy+ tool which comes with the visual studio from Microsoft that the application is unsing SWT_Windows and similar classes. Could it be a mixed UI application which uses for example Swing and SWT? I asked the guys who gave me the application but they haven't developed it on their own, and are now forwarding the question. 

Thanks so far for all the help!

Comment: The developers of that application said that they are using only Java SWT. I send them the Method and asked if they have any clue why their application seems to not have an UI Thread for a SWT Display. My only theory right now is that they done something special with their UI-Thread.